# PHP : Best way to push data from server to clients.....?

Tags: php, zend-framework, client-server

In my project `I need to push some data from server to the client` like `facebook` does, when `some updates are performed in the clients profile` like somebody writes something in the wall of the client, Facebook automatically push it to the client side.

Currently `I am using AJAX` to continuously `check the DB for the updates`. That is `not a good practice`.

I don't want to depended on the client side for the updates. I want that the `server should automatically push the data to the client side` when some updates are performed related to the client.

Please suggest some url or sample code to do so......

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: You're looking for [push techniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology). There are a number of implementations, check what's good for you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should take a look at the APE Project, which supports multiple variations that are as close to Push as you will get, like long-polling, XHRStreaming and WebSockets.

- http://www.ape-project.org/
- http://www.ape-project.org/wiki/index.php/Tutorial:Use_different_transport_method_(JSONP,_XHRStreaming)#Long_Polling

*edit*
Doing this in just PHP is not the best choice, as it takes up a lot of resources to keep all those connections alive.

Answer (score 1):

you can use node.js:  http://nodejs.org/

Comment: You have a link to a push example at hand?

Comment: @hakre [here you are](http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/nodejs-and-a-simple-push-notification-server/)

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a comet/websocket approach, i do not know any PHP comet implementations/frameworks, yet there are several examples on the web when you search for it.