# autoupdate webpage

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to make an auto update page, like facebook, of twitter?
There's one solution that I know. I can do that with ajax or jquery that send request to the server every t seconds.
but, I think it's too risky, because if I have 1000 users access the pages, so the server will receive too many request from the users.

Is there any other way to do it??
thanks for your help..

Comment: This is a similar question, might help you : [PHP : Best way to push data from server to clients…?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753674/php-best-way-to-push-data-from-server-to-clients)

Answer (score 3):

Try this in the page where u want refresh page. Here i gave 10sec. i.e. after foreavh 10secs it'll refresh the page so it'll automatically loads that page at every 10secs so u do ur update in that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='10' >");
</script>
```

Comment: I think this is a terrible approach to the problem that does not even answer the question. If your user is in the middle of some action and you refresh the page, he'll lost his data and you may have lost a user.

Answer (score 2):

The only way you can recieve information is by sending requests, if sending too many requests is a problem, then your stuck.

However, you don't have to do full page updates, why don't you just have auto refresh on important areas and do small individual requests for the areas you wish to update?

Answer (score 1):

Try reading about [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)

Unfortunately there is no other method then request/wait/response.

Read some more about [scalability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability) just to be able to start your system on the right track.

However, just try to avoid premature optimisation and over engineering, so you will be able to be up and running in short time with your site