# Chrome extension extracts wrong metadata without full page reload (discrepancy between original HTML and browser's interpretation)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, metadata

I have a Chrome extension browser action that extracts the metadata from a current tab. It works as expected, except on certain webpages (e.g., YouTube) where elements (e.g., description) are *not* from the current page, but are from the homepage (or where the last manual page refresh occurred within the same domain). The title and URL are always being retrieved correctly, but using different code (chrome.tabs.query).

An example of the script code for meta description (using chrome.tabs.executeScript):

```
var descriptionElement = document.querySelector("meta[name=\'description\']");
if (descriptionElement != null) 
  descriptionElement = descriptionElement.getAttribute("content");
```

This code will return, "Share your videos with friends, family, and the world" (which is the homepage meta description) on any YouTube.com page, unless I reload the page or arrive there from a direct link.

**I've noticed that the original HTML ("View page source") is always correct, but Chrome Developer Tools Elements is displaying the incorrect head data.**

How can I extract the current tab without requiring a full page reload? Is there a way other than querySelector that can bypass the browser's rendering and access the HTML directly?

Comment: Check out this article on How to push new HTML data from the server to the browser without refreshing the page.         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028921/how-to-push-new-html-data-from-the-server-to-the-browser-without-refreshing-the        it should hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: @Sean Carroll Unless I'm mistaken, my issues aren't a result of websockets. It's not as though the webpages are sending new data. For example: Simply go to YouTube.com. Click on any video. Check the <meta name="description"> data in the Chrome Developer Tools. It's wrong. Refresh the page. Now it's right.

Comment: "View page source" re-retrieves the page, so it's the same as if you refreshed it. Seems like YouTube navigation (that does not actually navigate but manipulates history state) does not refresh that part of the DOM, and therefore it's not the extension's fault. Developer Tools represent the DOM as it actually is.

Comment: @Xan I think this is definitely the issue here. Any ideas how I might circumvent this? Is there a way to access the offending DOM parts (e.g., <meta name="description">) without a page refresh? Also, why would a website not want some of the metadata to be relevant in the DOM?

Comment: Why? I assume it's because `<meta>` fields are more for robots and such which will not use JS-based navigation. You could either scrape the page with an XHR (which will return the same as page source does) or construct another query that looks for the description on the page.

Comment: @Xan Thanks! Queries on the page will be site-specific obviously (e.g., searching by id), so I'm curious how to scrape with an XHR. Read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765031/scrape-eavesdrop-ajax-data-using-javascript) but isn't exactly clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube supports [Microdata](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/microdata.html), and stores the latest description of the page in a `<meta itemprop="description" content="...">` tag within the body. To make use of this feature, replace your `meta[name="description"]`  selector with `meta[itemprop="description"]`.

YouTube uses pushState-based navigation to update the document's view without really "reloading" the page. That's why there is a discrepancy between the live DOM and the view-source DOM. If you want to detect when such a navigation occurs, read [this answer to "Chrome extension is not loading on browser navigation at YouTube"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18397962/chrome-extension-is-not-loading-on-browser-navigation-at-youtube/18398921#18398921).

---

On pages that do not support microdata, but behave as described in your question, you could fetch the page and query the DOM using the following snippet (assuming that you [have host permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions) for the page):

```js
var url = 'https://www.youtube.com/'; // e.g. from tab.url
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open('GET', url);
x.responseType = 'document';
x.onload = function() {
    var doc = x.response;
    var desc = doc.querySelector('meta[name="description"]');
    if (desc) {
         desc = desc.getAttribute('content');
         // Do something, e.g. show in dialog:
         alert(desc);
    }
};
x.send();
```

Answer (score -1):

OK, I get what you mean, I had a similar issue a while ago when I was trying to automatically goto a dynamically created #anchor on another page.  to get it to work I used.

```
<body onload="goToAnchor();">
<script type="text/javascript">
   function goToAnchor() 
   {
     location.href = "#openModal";
   }
</script>
```

maybe you could use the onload=yourFuntion(); to achieve what you require?

hope this helps.

Comment: This makes zero sense as an answer to this question.

Comment: First off, can't put inline script (onload="") into a chrome extension. _Can_ put it into the js file itself, however. In any case, I'm already using '$(document).ready'. Doesn't seem to be an issue with timing of load.